# How can I send auto generated non-authenticate mail from JAVA-mail from GCloud compute instance.

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, jakarta-mail, gcloud

Since port 25 is Blocked in GCLoud instance. How can I send auto generate mail without using MailGun and other paid service. And I have domain(mydomain.com) on GoDaddy. How can I make my instance send mail as gpaul@mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use appengine or set up your own mail server using a non-standard port. See the [sending-mail tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) for details.

Comment: I am new to GCloud. Can you please elaborate more on this. How to set up smtp other then port 25, 465, 587